# How to get the order of an item in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm new to python... I'm sorry if my question sounds too amateurish.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I need a function that gives me the position (or index when I give it the item)

for example, the index of 4 would be 3..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list.index(4)
3
```

The built-in list method index will return the index position of the first value located which is specified in the index method's argument.

Comment: And you can do "[i for i,j in enumerate(my_list) if j == valueToFind]" to get an array of indexes when there are multiple values

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4].index(4)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need more alternative to access your list, you can create tuple of pair of index and value

```
>>> l = list(enumerate([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]))            
>>> l
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 4)]
```

With list of tuples, you can access or filter based on index or value
For example :

Filter : Return all indexes with value = 3

```
>>> [tup[0] for tup in l if tup[1]==3]
[2, 3]
>>> [tup for tup in l if tup[1]==3]
[(2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Filter : Return value of index = 3

```
>>> [tup[1] for tup in l if tup[0]==4]
[4]
```